# I can't serve static by nginx

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I have the following nodejs structure which is resides in /home/ubuntu/project directory:

```
 sever
 site
   |-css
   |  |-styles.css
   |-img
   |  |-sprite.png
   |-js
     |-script.js
```

I'm trying to serve static assets by nginx, so I wrote the following location:

```
upstream myapp_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.myapp.com;

    error_page 400 404 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location  /50x.html {
            internal;
            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico|home/|html|xml) {
        root /home/ubuntu/project/site;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass         http://myapp_upstream;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

But when I try to open up my site in a browser I get failed status on all requested assets. Whet's the problem?

**EDIT:**
My route to css for example is:

```
http://www.myapp.com/css/styles.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Add a `/` to the root path.

```
root /usr/share/nginx/www;
```

should be

```
root /usr/share/nginx/www/;
```

Use an [alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#alias) for the assets like:

```
alias /home/ubuntu/project/site/; (again, add the last /)
```

These is a mess for me:

```
location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico|home/|html|xml)
```

You should check these http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#location

I dont see these folders  `images/, javascript/, stylesheets/, flash/, media/, static/ and home/` in your sitemap.

And these both `|html|xml`  are looking for the route `/html` or `/xml` not the `.html` or `.xml` files.

Then try:

```
location ~ ^/(robots.txt|humans.txt) {
    alias /home/ubuntu/project/site/;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}

location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {  //add here all the file extensions needed.
    alias /home/ubuntu/project/site/;
    access_log off;
    expires max;     
}
```

Comment: Hmm. That seems works but now I'm getting another issue. When I try to request css like http://www.myapp.com/css/styles.css I get resirect to http://www.myapp.com/css/styles.css/ with 403 error

Comment: Yes I solved the problem by adding root instead alias with '/' at the end